# Why do we need lseek when pread accepts offset value?

Tags: c++, posix, lseek

I am having trouble to understand why `lseek` function is useful.
Assuming I got a parameter like this given to me from the user:

```
off_t offset = 10;
```

And I wanted to read from the offset 100 bytes.
I can use `pread` like this:

```
void * buf = malloc(100);
if (buf == NULL) { exit(1);}
int res = pread(file_id, buf, 100, offset);
```

On the other hand, I understand I can set the file with `lseek` like this:

```
off_t seek = lseek(file_id, offset, SEEK_SET);
```

So I believe I achieve reading using `pread` already. What did I miss regarding `lseek` in what it can do to help me read the file?

Comment: Neither lseek nor pread are part of Standard C++. Or of Standard C, for that matter.

Comment: My bad, what would you name it? C? Linux?

Comment: It looks more like C code than C++. I've added a POSIX tag.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Why does that matter?

Comment: @NeilButterworth If its going through a `C++` compiler then it is `C++` code.

Comment: @Galik Because we don't want the C++ tag being swamped with questions specifically about the millions of non-standard APIs that are out there.

Comment: @NeilButterworth So why do we even have tags like `posix` and `lseek` and `mysql` etc...?

Comment: @Galik That question makes no sense. We have those tags for questions about posix and linux. I've already tagged this as posix.

Comment: @NeilButterworth there are 500K questions tagged "c++", I don't think you are going to be able to avoid "swamping"

Comment: The simple answer is that `lseek()` came first, by about 30 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function may have to read/write from/to a given file handle at a location that is not known to it (say current position), so you need to uncouple seeking from reading (or writing) because the caller may have a need to set the location.

More generally, many I/Os are just sequential so seeking is not necessary, while `pread` forces seeking.